# Can empathy be configured to stay updated will a full conversation?

Tags: empathy, google-talk

The Google Talk web app and Android app will always update themselves with all messages sent from all clients and I was wondering if Empathy can be configured to do this.

For example, if I start a conversation on my phone and then change to my PC an use the web app, all the messages I sent will show up in the IM window on the PC even though I sent them when I was on my phone.

Empathy does not behave this way. It only shows the IMs that occurred when using Empathy.

If Empathy cannot do this, is there any other client that can do it ?